# twig not retrieving a username from a controller?

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I'm only seeing a user id associate with my todos, it should pull a username being that the todo is associate with the user, maybe its my controller not pulling the right information or maybe it's something else, this is using slim and eloquent by the way.

`task.user_id.username` doesn't work just `task.user_id` does show the number associate with the user.

todos twig

```
{% extends "templates/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>My Todos</h1>

<ol>
  {% for task in tasks %}
        <div id="task{{task.id}}" class="myl" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <li><h4>{{ task.task}}</h4></li>
        <small style="font-style:italic">{{task.created_at |date("m/d/Y")}}</small></br>
        <small style="font-style:italic">{{task.user_id.username}}</small></br>




    <button id="disappear" name="task" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask({{task.id}})">Delete</button>



        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</ol>
{% endblock %}
```

todos controller

```
public function getTodos($request, $response, $args)
{


    $tasks = Task::with('user')->get();

    return $this->c->view->render($response, 'todos.twig', ['tasks' => $tasks]);

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `task.username` and not `task.user_id.username`? Right now ,you're trying to fetch the username from an integer.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah that didn't work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at some other posts on here i changed my code to this

i had to match my model classes with user_id for belongs to for BOTH classes and not just one.

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];
    public $timestamps = [];


    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Task', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Task.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


// use Slim\Views\Twig as View;
// use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $fillable = ['task', 'user_id'];


    public $timestamps = [];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

From here i can reference the username like so

```
{% extends "templates/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>My Todos</h1>

<ol>
  {% for task in tasks %}
        <div id="task{{task.id}}" class="myl" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <li><h4>{{ task.task}}</h4></li>
        <small style="font-style:italic">{{task.created_at |date("m/d/Y")}}</small></br>


        <small style="font-style:italic">
          {{ task.user.username}}

        </small>


        </br>




    <button id="disappear" name="task" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask({{task.id}})">Delete</button>



        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</ol>
{% endblock %}
```